# Why we don't study $\Re (f)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, soft-question

When we study a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on real line we try to find the domain of $f$ where $f$ takes real values, then study the key properties of that function on the domain (like continuity, differentiability, derivatives etc).

Instead of that we could think of the function $\Re (f)$ 
 where$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and study those properties in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

This question arose in my mind when I was studying the function $$\ln x \ln (1-x)$$
Note that $\Re (\ln x \ln (1-x))$ is continuous and differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%20x%20ln%20(1-x)).

On the other hand consider the function $$\sqrt{x}$$

Note that $\Re (\sqrt{x})$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$, but not differentiable a the point $x=0$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%20%7Bx%7D).

And there is a well known function $$\ln x$$
$\Re (\ln x)$ is not even continuous at $x=0$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%20x)

**Books which covers Real Analysis** do not mention these properties.

Someone may argue that these things are mentioned in **Complex analysis** (which I don't know for sure, since I have not studied Complex Analysis deeply), **why should this be in Complex Analysis when we are clearly working on Real field?**

Any thoughts/comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is this $\Re (f)$?

Comment: @Jack The real part of $f(x)$.

Comment: For a function $f:{\bf R}\to{\bf R}$, this is exactly the same thing as $f$. What is the question?

Comment: @Jack I think OP's asking why we don't study $\Re(f)$ for functions $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb C$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt you are right

Comment: I just don't feel like its very useful.  Doesn't relate to much you learn about in real analysis, so what would be the point of learning about these things in real analysis?  If you wanted such functions, you'd probably just use things such as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt x,&x\ge0\\0,&x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: If @SimplyBeautifulArt is right, please rewrite your question to clarify this issue.

Comment: All the examples in OP are real-valued, it does not make sense to talk about $\Re{f}$.

Comment: @Jack I'm pretty sure $\sqrt x$ is $\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb C$, consider the *entire* real line.  Same for $\ln(x)$.

Comment: If one is considering $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ as a function from ${\bf R}$ to ${\bf C}$, then one is already talking about complex roots, which means $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is considered as a function from ${\bf C}$ to ${\bf C}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher it's done!

Comment: @MANMAID : It's hard to understand what you want to know, but if you are interested in discussing $\ln x\ln(1-x)$ with complex $x$ then it can be useful to know, that $\,\ln x\ln(1-x)=$ $\frac{\pi^2}{6}- \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2}$ $- \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1-x)^k}{k^2}$ (dilogarithm) for $|x|\leq 1$ and $|1-x|\leq 1$ .

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't really make sense. We don't study $f$ on its range, we study it on its domain.

Comment: @zhw. you may check now, it is just a "concept typo", you can say. I meant what you said, I just wrote it wrongly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results Wolfram Alpha shows you are a little bit misleading. Without complex analysis, one cannot even understand correctly the results there.

In real analysis, the square root function $f(x)= \sqrt{x}$ is *defined* only for $x\geqslant 0$, not the whole real line. Similarly, the (real) logarithm $g(x):=\ln(x)$ is *defined* only for $x>0$. For the graph of $f$, one should look at the `real-valued plot`:

> [image]

On the other hand, one can define $f$ and $g$ with *complex* variables, and then *restrict* them on the whole real line.  In order to do so, one need to work in the realm of complex analysis.

For instance, the principal complex square root $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ is defined as
$$
f(x+iy)=\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}e^{i\theta/2}\tag{1}
$$
where $-\pi<\theta\leqslant \pi$ is such that $x+iy=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\theta}$. By restricting $f$ on the real line, one as
$$
f(x)=|x|^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}=|x|^{1/2}[\cos(\theta/2)+i\sin(\theta/2)]
$$
and 
$$
\Re(f)(x)=|x|^{1/2}\cos(\theta/2).
$$
Here $\theta=0$ when $x>0$ and $\theta=\pi/2$ when $x<0$.

---

Of course, functions from ${\bf R}$ to ${\bf C}$ are not always arise in this way (restriction of complex variable functions) and there are lots of them in real analysis!

For instance, $f(t)=e^{it}:=\cos t+i\sin t$ *is* a function from ${\bf R}$ to ${\bf C}$. When defining its Riemann integral on some closed interval $[a,b]$, one defines it by considering $\Re(f)$ and $\Im(f)$.

Comment: Very nice Jack. But you could just say that to study $\Re(f): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, we need to study Complex analysis.

Comment: [You are welcome.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Let me add something else. There are some subtleties.

Comment: On the other hand my question was different.. When someone study real analysis they don't get this knowledge, but it is purely about real analysis

Comment: Anyway as for your elaborate answer I have to accept it and you also gave the point anyway.

Comment: Well, one can totally ignore the "complex analysis" part in the explanation for the moment if one does not know what it is yet and may return later to see how it makes sense.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: thanks! I will correct it right now.

Answer (score 1):

$\Re (f)$ is the real part of a **complex valued** function, and we can study it only starting from the complex value of this function.

In other words: the value of $\Re (f)$ for a function as $f(x)=\ln x \ln (1-x)$ for $x<0$ or $x>1$ cannot be determined without the knowledge of Complex Analysis and it is not covered by books on Real Analysis .